# linking two plots to one drop down menu in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am working on a shiny app and I have two plots that I would like to link to one selectInput. So the user selection will update both graphs.

Is there a way to achieve this?

my code

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#ui
shinyUI(
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("NYC Flights Delays 2013"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("select", "Select a month", 
                  choices = list("2013","January" ,"February",
                                 "March","April",
                                 "May", "June",
                                 "July","August",
                                 "Septemeber","October",
                                 "November","December")
      )),

    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("monthlyavg",width="900",height = "400px")
    )
    ))


#server
function(input, output){
  output$monthlyavg<-renderPlotly({
    if (input$select =="January") {
      #calculate avg delay for departures and arrivals each month
        average_delay_month<-flight%>%
        group_by(flight_month)%>%
        summarise(Average_Departure_Delay=mean(dep_delay[dep_delay>0]),Average_Arrival_Delay=mean(arr_delay[arr_delay>0]))
      #filtering according to month
      average_delay_month<-subset(average_delay_month,flight_month=="January")

      #average delay by month(January)
      c<-average_delay_month %>%gather("metrics", "value", -flight_month)%>%
        ggplot(aes(flight_month, value, group= metrics, fill = metrics)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=.5, position = "dodge")+
        labs(title="Average Delay by Month", x="Flight Month",y="Average Delay in Minutes")
      print(c)

      #--January--#
      #--All Months Flight count--#
      flight$flight_month<-factor(flight$flight_month, levels=c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", 
                                                                "June","July","August",'September',"October","November","December"))
      #count number of flights per month
      flight_month_count<-setNames(aggregate(year~flight_month,data=flight,FUN=length),
                                   c('Month','Flight_Count'))
      flight_month_count<-subset(flight_month_count,Month=="January")
      #flight month_count_graph
      p<-ggplot(data=flight_month_count)+
        geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="#008080",aes(Month,Flight_Count),width=0.5)+
        labs(title="Total Number of Flights per Month",x="Flight Month",y="Number of Flights")
      print(p)
      }
```

I tried adding the two graphs (c) and (p) under one renderPlotly but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I tried adding the two graphs (c) and (p) under one renderPlotly but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

I would advise against this.

Option 1. Use two `renderPlotly` calls, with both depending on the same `input$select`

Option 2: Create a `mydata <- reactive({...})` object with your data processing steps within. Then in your two separate `renderPlotly` calls, reference `mydata()`. This will be updated anytime a new selection in made.

Comment: I am curious as to why you would advise against it?